# Reopening a seemingly poor "is a duplicate" question?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23354997/1079354).  Not the best quality, but after a few whacks with a thesarus and a spellcheck, it'll be good as new.

The main question asks if it's possible to return two values from a function.  Yes, that means it smells like [a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832472/how-to-return-2-values-from-a-java-function).  However, upon further clarification from the OP, it now smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/175248) as opposed to it being a verbatim duplicate.

- The question asks if they could return the modified value of a variable, which is done inside of their method.
- The method actually only returns a `char` for it to be used later in a `toString()` call.
- The *real* problem is that the value is modified *after* a call to the method, which seems more like a design flaw than an attempt to return two values at once.  This is entirely answerable, and it isn't really a duplicate of the aformentioned question at all.

Does anyone else have any thoughts on this?  I've already cast a reopen vote.  Further, what is the best approach that one should have when they come across questions that seem like they're sort of duplicates but really aren't (and put on hold because of it)?

Comment: I agree with your position, and I believe you made the right decision. If it's not really a duplicate vote to reopen, and edit if was poorly written but still is able to be a good question.

Comment: I've just run into a similar issue with a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073340/warning-mysql-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given-in-n) (not mine) I believe was unjustly marked as duplicate. I edited it to make it more clear, but I don't see a `reopen` button. Guessing I don't have the rep for that, but wondering if there are other routes to take to bring justice to the OP ;)